# How can this current division happen?

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-analysis, current

[image]

As far as I know, current division for spesific place's formula is:
Ix=(Req/Rx)*Isource   However, here,the solution is 3/(3+2+4)*6. How is this a current division ? Can you explain this to me

Comment: That's the right formula - work it out using ohms law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow the reasoning in the given solution, but I recommend that instead of memorizing a "current divider formula" in terms of resistors, you remember it in terms of conductors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVbcyL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$I_2 = I_s\frac{G_2}{G_1+G_2}$$

or

$$I_2 = I_s\frac{1/R_2}{1/R_1 + 1/R_2}$$

Then it's easy to see, since your current divider involves a 3 kohm resistor, and a series combination of 2 and 4 kohms, and you want the current through the series combination, the current will be

$$i = i_s\frac{1/6}{1/3+1/6} = i_s\frac{1}{2+1}$$

which gives the same result as in the presented answer (2 mA).

Comment: First of all thank you. However, i didn't exactly understand .This is the formula for what , and what does G represent ? and why is it not R2/ Req ?

Comment: @JuanDoe, G is the conductance of the resistor (i.e. the reciprocal of resistance). The constant in Ohm's law when written in the form \$I = GV\$.